# Занесение html элемента в объект JS

Tags: javascript, html

Хотел создать универсальный объект для управления всплывающего окна. Проблема в том что js не отображает это окно:
Пример кода на HTML:

```
<div id="notification">
  <div class="modal">  
    <span class="close"></span>  
    <p>Уведомление</p>
    <button id="Accept">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример кода на JS:

```
var noti = {
  modal : document.getElementById(notification),
  btnAccept : document.getElementById("Accept"),
  span : document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]
  };
noti.modal.style.display = "block";//при попытке вывести значение в alert выдает пустую строку
```

В дальнейшем хотел подвязать на объект события по нажатию на кнопку:

```
noti.btnAccept.onclick =  CloseNotificationWindow();
noti.span.onclick = CloseNotificationWindow();
```

Хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то управлять окнами таким способом через объект?

Comment: Выведите значение в консоль и посмотрите, что там лежит.

Comment: `noti.btnAccept.addEventListener('click', CloseNotificationWindow);` ?

Comment: @SwaD В консоль объект попадает нормальный, правильно берет HTML объекты, ругается на "noti.btnAccept.onclick =  CloseNotificationWindow();"

Comment: @Quazimorda Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Я думаю "()" лишнее, когда вы навешиваете событие `onClick`

Comment: @OliverPatterson как раз. когда через onClick - скобки не лишние.

Comment: Сделал как сказал @Quazimorda, больше не ругается на ошибки, но почему то display = "block" все равно не отрабатывает, окно не открывается.

Comment: @ДмитрийХарченко, так судя по названию, функция CloseNotificationWindow - у вас закрывать модальное окно должна.

Comment: @Quazimorda ну этот event должен висеть на кнопке "ок", но я даже кнопки не вижу, он не прорисовывает <div id="notification">

Comment: Блин, так `modal : document.getElementById('notification'),` - кавычек в названии id же не было у вас, вот и не виден div

Comment: @Quazimorda прошу прощения тут не указал кавычки у меня туда переменная падает с id выбранного окна

Comment: @Quazimorda попробовал жестко прописать id без переменной в кавычках, результат тот же, не открыл(

Comment: @Quazimorda, `как раз. когда через onClick - скобки не лишние`, с чего вы такое взяли?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, ну, скажем, возможны обе формы записи.

Comment: @Quazimorda, да.. Если бы функция возвращала еще одну функцию. Тогда нужно с `()`, но в данном случае чтобы передать ссылку на функцию, не нужно писать после ее названия `()`, дабы вызвать ее и вернуть результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот:

```js
var noti = {
  modal : document.getElementById('notification'),
  btnAccept : document.getElementById("Accept"),
  span : document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]
  };
noti.modal.style.display = "block";

function CloseNotificationWindow() {
  noti.modal.style.display = "none";
}

noti.btnAccept.addEventListener('click', CloseNotificationWindow);
noti.span.addEventListener('click', CloseNotificationWindow);
```

```css
#notification {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="notification">
  <div class="modal">  
    <span class="close"></span>  
    <p>Уведомление</p>
    <button id="Accept">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```